# Calculate remaining download time

Tags: javascript, math, time

I am uploading files via Ajax in chunks. At the moment, each chunk weighs 50 KiB.

In the upload process I have the following information:

- File size
- Amount of chunks
- Time started
- How long it took to upload current chunk in ms

I can also add pretty much anything that could be needed to complete this, what I have thought of is not to rely on upload speed, but to rely on average chunk upload time, this is my current broken formula:

```
(averageUplTime * ((FileSize / ChunkSize) ) -  AmountOfChunks) / 1000
```

It actually almost works, I can see between numbers that that it's decreasing in almost correct way, but i get these long numbers `9.16174` and I can't figure out right way to do this.

Comment: What's the question? Do you just want the rounded number?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev No the formula is incorrect, i was hoping some one could figure out a better one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `startTime` is a timestamp in milliseconds since the epoch, this should work:

```
var elapsedTime = (new Date().getTime()) - startTime;
var chunksPerTime = currentChunk / elapsedTime;
var estimatedTotalTime = amountOfChunks / chunksPerTime;
var timeLeftInSeconds = (estimatedTotalTime - elapsedTime) / 1000;

var withOneDecimalPlace = Math.round(timeLeftInSeconds * 10) / 10;
```

This is only "accurate" as long as the upload speed doesn't fluctuate very much. You can get better results by only considering the last X chunks to calculate `chunksPerTime` (and averaging about the last Y values of these).

Comment: Thank you so much, it's 99% accurate! i was working on this four hours :D

Comment: @Linas You're welcome. If it's unclear why exactly this works, just ask.